# Download file in AsyncTask with OneDrive SDK throws NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to Android development. Please let me know should there be any more detail I should add.

As far as I know, AsyncTask is using a worker thread, so it shouldn't cause NetworkOnMainThreadException. Is there anything I did wrong? Thanks.

I have intimated the structure of [OneDrive's Explorer](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-android) example.
I created an baseApplication extending Application, which includes an instance for IOneDriveClient.

```
/**
 * Base application
 */
public class OneDriveBaseApplication extends Application {
    public static final String Log_Tag = "MyDebug";

    /**
     * The service instance
     */
    private final AtomicReference<IOneDriveClient> mClient = new AtomicReference<>();

    /**
     * Create the client configuration
     * @return the newly created configuration
     */
    private IClientConfig createConfig() {
        final MSAAuthenticator msaAuthenticator = new MSAAuthenticator() {
            @Override
            public String getClientId() {
                SharedPreferences onedrivePref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.onedrive_pref_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String msa_client_id = onedrivePref.getString(getString(R.string.onedrive_pref_app_key), "");
                Log.v(Log_Tag, msa_client_id);
                return msa_client_id;
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getScopes() {
                return new String[]{"onedrive.appfolder offline_access"};
            }
        };

        final IClientConfig config = DefaultClientConfig.createWithAuthenticator(msaAuthenticator);
        config.getLogger().setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.Debug);
        return config;
    }
    /**
     * Used to setup the Services
     *
     * @param activity       the current activity
     * @param serviceCreated the callback
     */
    synchronized void createOneDriveClient(final Activity activity, final ICallback<Void> serviceCreated) {
        final DefaultCallback<IOneDriveClient> callback = new DefaultCallback<IOneDriveClient>(activity) {
            @Override
            public void success(final IOneDriveClient result) {
                mClient.set(result);
                serviceCreated.success(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(final ClientException error) {
                serviceCreated.failure(error);
            }
        };
        new OneDriveClient
                .Builder()
                .fromConfig(createConfig())
                .loginAndBuildClient(activity, callback);
    }

    /**
     * Get an instance of the service
     *
     * @return The Service
     */
    synchronized IOneDriveClient getOneDriveClient() {
        if (mClient.get() == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unable to generate a new service object");
        }
        return mClient.get();
    }
}
```

And in my fragment, I created an asynctask class to download files.

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        final OneDriveBaseApplication app = (OneDriveBaseApplication)getActivity().getApplication();
        try {
            app.getOneDriveClient()
                    .getDrive()
                    .getSpecial("approot")
                    .getChildren()
                    .buildRequest()
                    .get(new DefaultCallback<IItemCollectionPage>(getActivity()) {
                        @Override
                        public void success(final IItemCollectionPage result) {
                            Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "get children success");
                            if (result != null) {
                                for (final Item childItem : result.getCurrentPage()) {
                                    try {
                                        final String itemId = childItem.id;
                                        final String itemName = childItem.name;
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                        int len = 0;
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "name " + itemName + " id " + itemId);
                                        final File firDownloadDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "downloaded_files");
                                        firDownloadDir.mkdir();
                                        final File file = new File(firDownloadDir, itemName);
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "File path " + file.getPath());
                                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "FileOutputStream Established");

                                    /* Get the file from OneDrive*/
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "To get the file from OneDrive");
                                        InputStream in = app.getOneDriveClient()
                                                .getDrive()
                                                .getItems(itemId)
                                                .getContent()
                                                .buildRequest()
                                                .get();
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "Get the file from OneDrive succesfully");
                                        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                        }
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "Write successfully: " + childItem.name);
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "File not found when downloading: " + childItem.name);
                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "IOException when writing/reading: " + childItem.name);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                            Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "ClientException");
                        }
                    });
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
            Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "UnsupportedOperationException");
        } catch (Error error) {
            Log.v(OneDriveBaseApplication.Log_Tag, "Error for whatsoever");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And execute it with

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
downloadTask.execute();
```

However, it results a NetworkOnMainThreadException when sending a GET request.

```
202: Starting to send request, URL https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/AB76E7297xxxxxxx!110/content
206: Request Method GET
312: Error during http request
                  com.onedrive.sdk.core.ClientException: Error during http request
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.http.DefaultHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(DefaultHttpProvider.java:309)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.http.DefaultHttpProvider.send(DefaultHttpProvider.java:165)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.http.BaseStreamRequest.send(BaseStreamRequest.java:76)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.generated.BaseItemStreamRequest.get(BaseItemStreamRequest.java:60)
                    at tw.com.www.onedrivedemo.PlaceholderFragment$DownloadTask$1.success(PlaceholderFragment.java:159)
                    at tw.com.www.onedrivedemo.PlaceholderFragment$DownloadTask$1.success(PlaceholderFragment.java:133)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.DefaultExecutors$1.run(DefaultExecutors.java:88)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.SynchronousExecutor$1.onPostExecute(SynchronousExecutor.java:54)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.SynchronousExecutor$1.onPostExecute(SynchronousExecutor.java:46)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
                    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:300)
                    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:808)
                    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:76)
                    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
                    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:141)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.finishRequest(HttpTransport.java:52)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.http.UrlConnection.getResponseCode(UrlConnection.java:100)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.http.DefaultHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(DefaultHttpProvider.java:245)
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.http.DefaultHttpProvider.send(DefaultHttpProvider.java:165) 
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.http.BaseStreamRequest.send(BaseStreamRequest.java:76) 
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.generated.BaseItemStreamRequest.get(BaseItemStreamRequest.java:60) 
                    at tw.com.www.onedrivedemo.PlaceholderFragment$DownloadTask$1.success(PlaceholderFragment.java:159) 
                    at tw.com.www.onedrivedemo.PlaceholderFragment$DownloadTask$1.success(PlaceholderFragment.java:133) 
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.DefaultExecutors$1.run(DefaultExecutors.java:88) 
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.SynchronousExecutor$1.onPostExecute(SynchronousExecutor.java:54) 
                    at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.SynchronousExecutor$1.onPostExecute(SynchronousExecutor.java:46) 
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660) 
                    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java) 
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: possible diplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `OneDriveClient` is handling the async for you.

So you don't need to call what is essentially the setup of the request in an `AsyncTask`. You may want to put an `AsyncTask` inside the `success()` callback, as the problem is when you call `.get()` on the client. This is a blocking operation which will perform the action then and there on the current thread. In this case, that thread is the mainThread as `success` called from that thread.

Solution: understand which parts are async and move them off of the mainThread. Simplify your code so that you can understand what part is failing.

Use breakpoints and/or logs to see what thread you are on at different places.

Comment: Thanks! Using AsyncTask in inside the success() callback works.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your onPostExecute method?

This is good article for you: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when your app tries networking operation in main thread.
Try to use runOnUiThread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                // call your async task.
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In UIThread,you can't run  time-consuming operation like access to the network.So you should run it on other thread. You can try this:

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            downloadTask.execute();      
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried execute the downloadTask in "new Thread", but "NetworkOnMainThreadException" still happens.